# android端末でのudp通信につきまして

Tags: android, udp

andtoid端末でグローバルipを用いてudpパケットの通信を行うアプリを作成しています。現状はローカルipを利用したローカル環境では端末間のパケットの通信はできています。しかし、グローバル間だとパケットを受け取ることができません。コードは以下を参考にしています。
https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/
ルータのポートマッピング（ポート解放）、android端末の静的ipの割当は行っています。
ちなみに、上記プログラムをpcで動かした場合はグローバル間で通信はできました。
コードの誤り以外で、環境面などで見落としていることは何かあるでしょうか、ご教授お願いします。

以下、私の環境です。
携帯端末：Zenfone 2
Androidのバージョン:6.01(APIレベル23)
セキュリティアプリ:security master
ルータ:IODATA（ＷＮ-AG450DGR）

補足
masmさんの仰るように端末とルータの接続は以下の通りです。
端末 -- (Wi-Fi) -- ルータ -- (インターネット) -- ルータ -- (Wi-Fi) -- 端末
グローバルipとポート番号を指定して、通信をさせる予定です。

ネットワーク監視アプリ(net swiss tool free)でポートの状況を調べたところ、ローカルipを使用したときには問題ないですが、グローバルipを使用したときはポートがクローズされている状況です。

> sayuriさん
>   双方向です。両端末でパケットの送信と受信スレッドを別々に動かしています。現在はローカルipを使用したときのパケット通信は正常に動いています

以下の点は確認しています。
・ポート番号のかぶりはない
・指定している、ip、ポート番号は間違っていない
・AndroidmManifest.xmlにネットワークを扱うinternetのパーミッションはあたえている

> masmさん
>   portがクローズされていると判断したのは以下の結果のためです
>   ローカルip指定時:
>   portscan tcp(ルータでtcpも解放している)
>   →結果がopened
>   udp flood
>   →アプリ動作
>   グローバルip指定時:
>   portscan tcp
>   →closed
>   udp flood
>   →アプリ動作しない
>   ※このネットワーク監視アプリを使ってグローバルipを利用して、pcで起動している上記サンプルプログラムのポートに対してudp floodしたところ、正常に動きました。

補足2
グローバルipを指定したパケットの送信側は正常にできています。
※作成中のアプリからpcで起動している上記サンプルプログラムのサーバで受信できたため。

Comment: 「グルーバル間」の意味がよく解らないのですが、端末 -- (Wi-Fi) -- ルータ -- (インターネット) -- ルータ -- (Wi-Fi) -- 端末、こんな感じでしょうか?

Comment: 接続はその通りです。互いにグローバルip、ポート番号を指定して通信する形です。

Comment: 私がコメントに書いた図と、abc123さんのコメントを併せて、質問に追記していただけますか? 質問の下に「編集」というリンクがありますので、そこから質問を編集できます。

Comment: 質問で実現したいのは双方向通信でしょうか？ １方向は実現できていたりしないのでしょうか？

Comment: net swiss tool free にはいろいろな機能があるようですが、「グローバルipを使用したときはポートがクローズされている状況」と判断したのは、これらの機能の内 Netstat 機能を使ったのでしょうか?

Comment: ローカルip指定時に「ルータ」の単語があるのが気になります。ローカルip指定の場合に何故ルータのポート開放が関係あるのでしょうか? 端末 -- (Wi-Fi) -- ルータAP -- (Wi-Fi) -- 端末、なら、ルータのポート開放は関係ないと思います。それから、何故 tcp でチェックしたのか解りませんが、tcp の特定のポートが開いているかどうかと、udp の特定のポートが開いているかどうかは、全く無関係です。

Comment: ルータのログを確認してみるとか、端末とルータの間に別の機材を挟んでそこでパケットの中身を確認してみるとかすれば、何か解るかもしれませんね(前者はうちのルータにはログ表示機能がないので見れませんが、後者は私はよくやります)。また何か気づいたらコメントします。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。アドバイスのような試行錯誤してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

詳しい原因は分からないですが以下の結果になりました。

・送受信失敗
-グローバルip指定
端末a-- (Wi-Fi) -- ルータa -- (インターネット) -- ルータa -- (Wi-Fi) -- 端末a

・送受信成功
-グローバルip指定
端末a-- (Wi-Fi) -- ルータa -- (インターネット) -- ルータa -- (Wi-Fi) -- 端末b

-ローカルip指定
端末a-- (Wi-Fi) -- ルータa -- (Wi-Fi) -- 端末a

端末a-- (Wi-Fi) -- ルータa -- (Wi-Fi) -- 端末b

まずはじめに、自分の端末で送受信できるかと考えていたので、どつぼにはまってました。

コメントをしてくださった、masmさん、sayuriさんありがとうございます。